# Two Queries: Group by Column, Subtract Similar Columns, Show Totals

Tags: database, ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I have the following two queries setup in Access.  Each query has only 1 line per org and the org names are consistent across the two queries.

Query A (budget model based on Table A)

```
Org, Jan, Feb, ... Dec, Total
-----------------------------
A,   $68, $25, ... $51, $809
B,   $23, $39, ... $13, $423
...
E,   $11, $90, ... $84, $789
```

Query B (budget model based on Table B)

```
Org, Jan, Feb, ... Dec, Total
-----------------------------
A,   $67, $25, ... $70, $821
B,   $23, $39, ... $13, $423
...
E,   $15, $45, ... $71, $755
```

How can I create a report with all of the following information?  I'm having troubling bringing together the two queries, subtracting their values and then ultimately showing the totals rows all in the same report/query.

```
             Jan, Feb, ...  Dec,   Total
Org A:

    Model A: $68, $25, ..., $51,   $809
    Model B: $67, $25, ..., $70,   $821
    A - B  : $ 1, $ 0, ..., ($19), ($12)

Org B:

    Model A: $23, $39, ..., $13,   $423
    Model B: $23, $39, ..., $13,   $423
    A - B  : $ 0, $ 0, ..., $ 0,   $  0

...

Org E:

    Model A: $11, $90, ..., $84,   $789
    Model B: $15, $45, ..., $71,   $755
    A - B  :($ 4),$45, ..., $13,   $ 34

-------------------------------------------
Totals:

    Model A: $102, $154, ..., $148,   $2021
    Model B: $105, $109, ..., $154,   $1999
    A - B  :($ 3), $45, ..., ($ 6),   $  22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a UNION query with one set of values multiplied by -1, you can use a group sum on organization to get the subtraction in your report. The report wizard will do this for you.

```
SELECT "a" as Source, qa.Org, 
       qa.Jan, qa.Feb, qa.Dec, qa.Total
FROM qa
UNION ALL 
SELECT "b" as Source, qb.Org, 
       qb.Jan * -1, qb.Feb * -1, qb.Dec * -1, qb.Total * -1
FROM qb
```

You can group by source to create a summary that can be included as a subreport.